# Python Multiple inheritance doesn't seem to be "depth first". Or am i missing something obvious

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

```
class B:
    def f(self):
        return "p"

class C1(B):
   #no definition of f
   pass

class C2(B):
    def f(self):
        return "c2"

class G(C1,C2):
    pass


g = G()
print("I would expect this value to be 'p'. But it prints 'c2'",g.f())
```

According to python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance

*For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first, left-to-right, not searching twice in the same class where there is an overlap in the hierarchy. Thus, if an attribute is not found in DerivedClassName, it is searched for in Base1, **then (recursively) in the base classes of Base1**, and if it was not found there, it was searched for in Base2, and so on.*

That is definitely not happening.

Comment: If definitely *is* happening, you're just misunderstanding the documentation - see the answer below for an example that may help explain it.

Answer (score 0):

"That is definitely not happening." Sure it is.

Consider this:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        return "a"


class B:
    def f(self):
        return "b"


class C1(B):
    # no definition of f
    pass


class C2(B):
    def f(self):
        return "c2"


class G(C1, C2):
    pass


class H(C1, A):
    pass


g = G()
print("This prints 'c2' because it finds `f` in `C2` overriding the one in `B`.", g.f())
h = H()
print("This prints 'b' because it finds `f` in `B` ignoring the one in `A` even though it's 'closer'.", h.f())
```

Comment: The point i'm trying to highlight is that the algorithm here is not "depth first". if you search C1, and then its SIBLING (C2), the search is "breadth first". If it was truly depth first, it would search C1's parents before searching C2.